# Resize external javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can the `div` added by the below external javascript be resized?

Below I have attempted to wrap it in a div and set the width on the div, but it is not resizing.

```
<div width = "100"><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://static.polldaddy.com/p/23232.js"></script>
<noscript><a href="http://polldaddy.com/poll/23232/">Test</a></noscript>
</div>
```

The js adds a `div` to the page, and i want to resize that.

Note, this poll does not actually exist.

Comment: What do you mean, "resized"?  Scripts don't show up on the page at all; they have no size.

Comment: scripts don't have dimensions. If the script is writing HTML to your page, you need to modify the generated HTML or CSS to alter the dimensions of the rendered elements

Comment: Here is the solution(take a look at the CSS-window) http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/Fcc6B/

Comment: Here's another solution for you http://jsfiddle.net/AnCfV/

Answer (score 2):

## `<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://static.polldaddy.com/p/23232.js"></script>`

But serious as [Pointy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11193513/resize-external-javascript/11193641#comment14691539_11193513) already stated. Javascript shouldn't be visible on the page.